# how to fix 404 Page Error in such scenario?

Tags: php, drupal, http-status-code-404, drupal-6

I have Drupal Site. www.hello.com

Now, we have created a subdomain as dev.hello.com,if I enter the url in the browser as

- dev.hello.com - Site is rendered, No issue
- www.dev.hello.com - 404 Page Not Found

> We cannot locate the page you're looking for. Please check the address and make sure all letters are lowercased with no spaces.

How do I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

u can using .htaccess file in root directory .

Comment: This is heights... what you see in the post.. we are trying to find that rewrite rules only..